# Ничто, или запятая, или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

`1. Мы на Новый год много раз кого приглашали и нас тоже приглашали.`

`2. Мы на Новый год много раз кого приглашали, и нас тоже приглашали.`

`1. Мы на Новый год много раз кого приглашали – и нас тоже приглашали.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я выбираю второй вариант:

*Мы на Новый год **мнОго раз кого** приглашали, и **нАс** тоже приглашали.*

А как же **общий элемент**, а именно второстепенный член? На новый год ведь, об этом же речь!

Но общий элемент не есть нечто **обязательное**, чему всегда надо следовать. Это всего лишь **причина** для объединения предложений в одну фонетическую и смысловую фразу.

Поэтому смотрим на **структуру** предложения. Здесь нужно подчеркнуть ударением и противопоставить две ситуации, поэтому выделяем здесь **два сообщения**.

Вариант **с тире** отличается большей паузой, но в данном случае нет в этом необходимости. Нужное понимание **смысла** (деление предложения на две фразы) достаточно хорошо обозначено с помощью **грамматики** (дополнительный интонационный знак не кажется необходимым).

Comment: То есть беззапятной вариант стопроцентно некорректный?

Comment: Он представляется мне некорректным из-за сопоставления двух ситуаций, поэтому их приходится рассматривать отдельно, но не объединять.

Comment: То есть из-за того, что там вторая часть как бы является предложением добавочным, мы ставим запятую?

Comment: Оно не добавочное. а равноценное. Просто нам приходится их сравнивать, а поэтому разделять. Сравнить: На Новый год мы приглашаем друзей и у нас всегда весело. Здесь две ситуации можно объединить, нет запятой.